# Why two level of break has been removed in PHP7.1 and what could be it's alternate solution?

Tags: php, break, php-5.3, php-7.1

I was migrating production code from `PHP5.3` to `PHP7.1`, code had `break 2;` inside nested two level of while loop inside if condition, I got below error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot 'break' 2 levels

Why two level of break has been removed in PHP7.1 and what could be it's alternate solution?

Comment: Is my answer helpful with you?

Comment: at least it runs but need to re write logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this issue with change :

```
break 2;
```

By:

```
break;
```

You are into one loop and not two nested loops. That's why you can't "break 2" (because 2 denotes that you're inside a nested loop). The error appears because PHP7 is stricter than former versions.

Note: You can't "break" from an if statement. You can only break from a loop.